# How to get refresh_token in Okta using SPA or web app

Tags: reactjs, jwt, single-page-application, okta, okta-api

I'm using the [okta-auth-js](https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js) with SPA and I want to retrieve the refresh token.

My config is the following:

```
okta: {
    issuer: 'https://myIssuer/oauth2/default',
    clientId: '0oahHMKdu3BlV0x1hdoa7lV0',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/login/callback',
    responseType: 'code'
  }
```

And I perform the authentication like this:

```
oktaAuth.signInWithCredentials({
    username,
    password
  }).then((transaction) => {
      switch (transaction.status) {
        case 'SUCCESS': {
          const { sessionToken } = transaction;
          oktaAuth.token.getWithRedirect({ sessionToken });
          break;
        };
        ... // Other status cases
```

I have enable refresh token rotation in the Okta dashboard but I get only access_token and id_token as response.

My question is how to get the refresh_token also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution :)

You have to add the `offline_access` scope with the session token when you call `/authorize`.

For example:

```
oktaAuth.signInWithCredentials({
    username,
    password
  }).then((transaction) => {
          switch (transaction.status) {
            case 'SUCCESS': {
              const { sessionToken } = transaction;
              oktaAuth.token.getWithRedirect({
                sessionToken,
                scopes: ['openid', 'offline_access']
              });
              break;
            }
        ... // Other status cases
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `offline_access` in your scopes

[source](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/refresh-tokens/get-refresh-token/)